# Coding a time series Block RNN model. But getting NaN as predicted values

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

[this is how the dataset looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDpSx.png)

this is the code which I used for indexing the time-series data and forming a Block RNN model (the index used is a datetime index instead of normal integer indexing):

```
import pandas as pd
from darts import TimeSeries
from darts.utils.likelihood_models import Likelihood
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
csv_file = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# indexing
df['Year_Week'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Week'].astype(str)

# Converting the 'Year_Week' column to a datetime format with Sunday as the start of the week
df['Year_Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Week'] + '-0', format='%Y-%U-%w')

# Setting 'Year_Week' as the index of the DataFrame
df.set_index('Year_Week', inplace=True)

# Splitting data into train and test sets
train_size = 0.8
test_size = 0.2

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, train_size=train_size, test_size=test_size, shuffle=False)

train_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(train_data[['Cases']], freq='W')
test_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(test_data[['Cases']], freq='W')
train_covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(train_data[['Rain']], freq='W')
test_covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(test_data[['Rain']], freq='W')

from darts.models import BlockRNNModel

block_rnn_model = BlockRNNModel(input_chunk_length=30, output_chunk_length=13, n_rnn_layers=2)
block_rnn_model.fit(train_series, past_covariates=train_covariate_series, epochs=100, verbose=True)

block_rnn_predictions = block_rnn_model.predict(7)
print(block_rnn_predictions)
```

the output comes out to be:

```
TimeSeries (DataArray) (Year_Week: 7, component: 1, sample: 1)>
array([[[nan]],

       [[nan]],

       [[nan]],

       [[nan]],

       [[nan]],

       [[nan]],

       [[nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * Year_Week  (Year_Week) datetime64[ns] 2008-09-14 2008-09-21 ... 2008-10-26
  * component  (component) object 'Cases'
Dimensions without coordinates: sample
Attributes:
    static_covariates:  None
    hierarchy:          None
```

why is it showing values as NaN for the case predictions made? similar output is shown when NBEATS model, Transformer model and TCN model is used.